# Signature Panel

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

My requirements are I need a panel where user can make signature. The concept is like when user touches the screen and move the pointer, it should be marked with continuous line.

Please gimme some idea how to implement this??

Answer (score 1):

Subclass UIView and override the various UIResponder methods dealing with touch. Especially pay attention to `touchesMoved:withEvent:` - this is the method where you can get data about the previous/current points of the touch, and potentially add them to a set of points the touch has moved through. You can also override `drawRect:` in your custom UIView to draw a curve through all the points the touch has passed.

More info:

- [UIResponder reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [UIView reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

Comment: Additionally, one can use the CGContext path functions to draw the signature. Reference: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF101